# javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: could not device repository from class

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

Did anyone encounter this error when using jboss? I've been searching for possible causes but never found anything about it. I know it's a bit vague but I can't post full stacktrace unfortunately, no permission to do that. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be that the exception is thrown by your own code, or a third-party library that you are using.
Try to search in your source code the text "could not device repository from class", if it not appears, try to identify what class throws the exception and find out to whom it belongs (maybe a propietary framework)

Comment: Thanks Gabriel! It's not in our code but it could be a library that we're using. I'll try to find out which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed; the error appeared due to a third party framework